# Ускорить/замедлить видео

Tags: c#, uwp, видео

Как ускорить/замедлить видео, `mediaElement.PlaybackRate` тут я меняю у компонента `mediaElement`, а не у самого видео, само видео у меня хранится в `MediaComposition composition = new MediaComposition();` 
Потом мне надо это видео с измененной скоростью сохранить в файл.
По типу SlowMotionEffectDefinition

Как это можно сделать на UWP?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
var me = new MediaElement();
me.DefaultPlaybackRate = 0.5;
me.Play();
```

Comment: Это изменение скорости у MediaElementa не у самого видео